# How do I find out which gem has a specific dependency?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I commented out a gem, but 'bundle install' still won't run. How do I find out which gem has a dependency on sys-proctable?

```
$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Could not find sys-proctable-0.9.2 in any of the sources

$ grep proctable Gemfile
  #gem 'sys-proctable', '0.9.2', :path => "vendor/gems"

$ bundle list
Resolving dependencies...
Could not find gem 'rspec-rails (= 2.11.0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.

$ bundle viz
Resolving dependencies...
Could not find gem 'rspec-rails (= 2.11.0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.

$ bundle -v
Bundler version 1.3.0

$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p385 (2013-02-06 revision 39114) [i386-cygwin]
```

Gemfile: http://pastebin.com/9WWMfKtv

I've already tried these troubleshooting steps: https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/blob/1-2-stable/ISSUES.md

Comment: The Gemfile.lock normally shows you your dependencies, but I'm not sure it's generated yet for you since the bundler didn't complete successfully.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

In the bash shell you can do:

`gem dependency name_of_the_gem --reverse-dependencies`

For instance:

```
$ gem dependency activesupport --reverse-dependencies                        
Gem activesupport-2.3.14
Used by
actionpack-2.3.14 (activesupport (= 2.3.14))
activerecord-2.3.14 (activesupport (= 2.3.14))
activeresource-2.3.14 (activesupport (= 2.3.14))
```

Comment: That didn't work. `gem dependency --pipe sys-proctable` printed `test-unit --version '>= 2.4.0'`, but that gem isn't in my Gemfile either: `grep test-unit Gemfile`.

Comment: @Chloe could you try this then:  gem  dependency sys-proctable --reverse-dependencies,  I added the reverse dependency option to the command.

Comment: Yes! That works! `Used by
    guard-spork-1.2.0 (sys-proctable (>= 0))`

Comment: For me it worked only when specifying ``-b`` parameter ("``-b``, ``-​-both`` - Allow LOCAL and REMOTE operations")

Comment: This doesn't work if the gem is not actually installed.

Answer (score 10):

**I know this answer includes a link, but this is not a link specific answer**

You can always check the reverse dependencies of a gem on [rubygems.org](https://rubygems.org). There's a link on the right side panel on the website.

[image]

Or you can visit the site

> `https://rubygems.org/gems/{gem_name}/reverse_dependencies`

So, in your case

https://rubygems.org/gems/sys-proctable/reverse_dependencies

Answer (score 5):

> How do I find out which gem has a dependency on sys-proctable?

Try the [bundler-why](https://github.com/jaredbeck/bundler-why) plugin (inspired by [`yarn why`](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/why))

```sh
bundler plugin install bundler-why
bundle why tzinfo
# ransack -> activesupport -> tzinfo
# rspec-rails -> activesupport -> tzinfo
# business_time -> tzinfo
```

`gem dependency --reverse-dependencies` will traverse a single [edge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)) of the [paths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(graph_theory)). In comparison, `bundle why` will traverse all edges.